# New values into ID identity (1,1) column

Tags: sql, identity

Simplest example: I've got the following table:

```
create table test
    ( ID int identity (1,1) not null primary key,
      text char(20) not null
    )
```

I have already created 3 values:

- `(1,a)`
- `(2,b)`
- `(3,c)`

Now I delete `(2,b)`, and my rows are `(1,a)` and `(3,c)`.

- Is it possible to make it automatically `(1,a)` and `(2,c)`?
- Or do I have to create a procedure?

Comment: Do you want to keep the Id sequential without gaps? That's not how it works and there's no reason to do it. Please justify your question

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  Presuming SQL Server, you can use the `IDENTITY_INSERT` switch to allow direct specification of the identity values.  However, why use an identity column if you don't want to let SQL choose the values for you?

Comment: Greetings, I just wanted to have it ordered, from 1 to example 100, with 1 difference. But now I know that it would not be a good idea. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and you *shouldn't*.  There are too many ways that this can go bad - suppose you had related records in another table with `2` as a foreign key - instead of being orphaned (and easily identified as such) they would instead be related to a different (incorrect) record.

In addition, `IDENTITY` values are *usually* used as the clustered index (meaning they determine the physical storage location of the record).  If you change the value, the data will have to be physically relocated -which wont *hurt* anything but will cause unnecessary I/O.

`IDENTITY` values are not guaranteed to be *consecutive*, they're guaranteed to be *unique*.  If you need consecutive numbers, the best way is to derive that in your *output* by adding a `ROW_NUMBER` column:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) RowNum,
    ID,
    text
FROM test
```

However note that `RowNum` will be DIFFERENT if records in the middle are deleted (as you could guess).  So you can't build any *relationships* off of that value - you can just use it to show *consecutive ordering*.